# Display database image in RDLC report from a specific row in database

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2013, reporting, rdlc

working with VB.net and RDLC reports.  At the top of the report, I would like to show the company logo stored in my database.

I create an image and assign the image field from the database to it and it displays the image (this works).

Problem is it is pulling out the FIRST image in the database.

What I would like to do is show the image related to the specific company name.  Seems like RDLC doesnt allow this...

I am forced to pick: =First(Fields!CompanyLogo.Value, "MyCompanyInfo")

What I need is:

Fields!CompanyLogo.Value WHERE CompanyName is 'ABC'

Comment: SO you want to change the image logo for each report or each page ?

Comment: change the image logo for each report.  So at the top of the report, I want to pass a variable called Companyname and the logo will be displayed.

Comment: Then why does  `first` matters because logo will be same for that company. Or you are getting data for the all the companies at each time

Comment: Thanks @CoderofCode yes I have a table of all my company details and on of the fields is "companylogo".  So basically, if you login, the application will recognise that you are the director of company ABC and it will display relevant information for company ABC (including your logo)